# configure videojs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, video.js

I am trying to play videos using video player from videojs.com in visual studio 2012 express.

my web form is based on master page.
Following is the code for Master Page

```
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>

 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>

            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Following code is the page that needs to play video

```
<script  type="text/javascript">videojs('my_video_1').ready(function () {
var player = this;
player.play();

this.on('loadeddata', function () {
    player.currentTime(10);
});
});</script>
```

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin "
  poster="img/message.png"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360" data-setup='{}'>
<source src="Videos/Presentation.mp4" type='video/mp4' />

</video>
```

When I run the debugger, Presentation.aspx page runs and I get the following error

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 511 in http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Exception thrown and not caught

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
I am referencing https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.3.0/docs/guides/api.md for functionality but I am stuck on the first step.

throw new TypeError("The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)");

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The script tag needs to come after the video tag in the page, otherwise the video tag doesn't exist when the script is run.

Also don't use the data-setup attribute at the same time as manually calling videojs() to init the video. They accomplish the same thing and may cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same but my video is still able to download.
Actully I'm looking to prevent downloads of my video from any browser.
Please tell which one is the best approach.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>video</title>

    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <video controlsList="nodownload" id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin "
               poster="img/message.png"
               controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360" data-setup='{}'>
            <source src="~/Videos/Butterfly.mp4" type='video/mp4' />

        </video>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        videojs('my_video_1').ready(function () {
            var player = this;
            player.play();

            this.on('loadeddata', function () {
                player.currentTime(10);
            });
        });</script>
    </div>
</body>
```